# Extending angular.js jQlite with custom events

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

jQuery has a way to extend it with custom events. Is it possible to extend angularjs jQueryLite in the similar manner? For example, if I would like to bind custom event in directive like this:

```
link: function (scope, element, attr) {
    // mousewheel would be custom event
    element.on("mousewheel", function (event) {
        // event handling
    });
}
```

Comment: what exactly are you wanting to do? Angular itself has an event system and you can use `bind()` for any real element events

Comment: I wan't to create mousewheel wrapper like the one jquery has:  https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel , but using only angularjs.

Comment: if you include jquery before angular in page then `element` becomes a jquery object (instead of jQlite) that you can use plugins on

Comment: I know that. But the problem is that I don't wan't to use full jquery library. I need to do this using only api angularjs provides.

Comment: then port what you need from that plugin to angular

Comment: That's exactly what I want to do. But the problem is I don't know how can I do that. I wasn't able to find any documentation related to angularjs jquerylite extending.

Comment: nothing preventing you using native methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides [the list of jQuery API methods](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#angular-s-jqlite) that are mimicked by jqLite, there's no documentation on jqLite internals. Because they are internal indeed and aren't meant to be extended.

Unlike jQuery, jqLite offers no way to provide custom events, [it just wraps around DOM events](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.5.8/src/jqLite.js#L853-L896).

It is possible to support custom events by patching `angular.element.prototype.on`, `angular.element.prototype.off` and `angular.element.prototype.triggerHandler` methods. But it is not advisable and is certainly not how the things are supposed to be done in Angular.